scala-xml version conflict while runnning the command "sbt clean update"
sathvika@sathvika-vm:~/geotrellis-spark-hdfs$ sbt run
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jline.terminal.impl.exec.ExecTerminalProvider$ReflectionRedirectPipeCreator (file:/home/sathvika/.sbt/boot/scala-2.12.19/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.10.1/jline-terminal-3.24.1.jar) to constructor java.lang.ProcessBuilder$RedirectPipeImpl()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jline.terminal.impl.exec.ExecTerminalProvider$ReflectionRedirectPipeCreator
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[info] welcome to sbt 1.10.1 (Oracle Corporation Java 11.0.23)
[info] loading project definition from /home/sathvika/geotrellis-spark-hdfs/project
[info] loading settings for project geotrellis-spark-hdfs from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to geotrellis-spark-hdfs (in build file:/home/sathvika/geotrellis-spark-hdfs/)
[info] running HDFSFileChecker2
Raster(ArrayMultibandTile(1,1,4,uint8raw),Extent(-4007.50166856125, 1.2501004675868899E-9, -1.2501004675868899E-9, 4007.50166856125))
[success] Total time: 18 s, completed 05-Aug-2024, 7:22:02 AM
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/sathvika/geotrellis-spark-hdfs/target/bg-jobs/sbt_641180ba/target/5dca9fb7/359669fc/hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3089)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:3036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadProps(Configuration.java:2914)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1863)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1840)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.shutdownExecutor(ShutdownHookManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.access$300(ShutdownHookManager.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:102)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/sathvika/geotrellis-spark-hdfs/target/bg-jobs/sbt_641180ba/target/5dca9fb7/359669fc/hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:149)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1764)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1275)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:741)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource$FinalizableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:857)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:846)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:256)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:185)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:348)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:72)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:168)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.getOrCreate(JarFileFactory.java:91)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:3009)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getStreamReader(Configuration.java:3105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3063)
    ... 10 more


[error] (update) found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[error] * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:2.2.0 (early-semver) is selected over {1.2.0, 1.1.1, 2.1.0}
[error]      +- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.19              (depends on 2.2.0)
[error]      +- org.foundweekends.giter8:giter8-lib_2.12:0.16.2    (depends on 2.1.0)
[error]      +- com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.5.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (depends on 1.1.1)
[error]   +- com.typesafe.play:twirl-api_2.12:1.5.1   (depends on 1.2.0)
[error]

The above is the main challenge I am facing
Unable to understand which versions to be used (SBT, Scala-xml, geotrellis)
